# C# AspNetCore.Mvc bind json to class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am doing asp.net core web api for my react project. And I got stuck with parsing json POST request to the class.
 My action looks like this

```
     [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] RootObject request)
    {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(request);
        return null;
    }
```

And I am passing this POSTING this json

```
{
"survey": {
    "questions": [{
        "check": [null]
    }],
        "title": "dsfdf",
        "date": "dfdsfs",
        "notify": true
    }
 }
```

My RootObject class looks like this

```
 public class Question1
{
    public List<string> check { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Question1> questions { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

So problem is that request is always null. Any idea, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

JSON was wrong.
It should have been

```
{
"questions": [{
    "check": [null]
}],
    "title": "dsfdf",
    "date": "dfdsfs",
    "notify": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON representation should mimic your C# object representation (since you're using model binding)

Also make sure that the content type is the proper one (application/json) so that the proper serializer is used.

As such:

```
public class RootObject {
    [JsonProperty("questions")]
    public List<Question> Questions {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Question
{
    [JsonProperty("check")]
    public List<string> Check { get; set; }
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

Answer (score 0):

See this sample.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-post-complex-JSON-d15bb765

this is same to your scenario.

**The Model**

```
public class ItemGroup 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public IList<GroupItem> Items { get; set; } 
} 

public class GroupItem 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

**The Front end**

```
    var sendJsonData = { 
        Name: "Group1", 
        Items: [ 
            { 
                Id: 1, 
                Name: "Item1" 
            }, 
            { 
                Id: 2, 
                Name: "Item2" 
            }, 
            { 
                Id: 3, 
                Name: "Item3" 
            } 
        ] 
    }; 

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/Home/PostJson", 
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        data: JSON.stringify(sendJsonData), 
        success: function (data) { 

        } 
    });
```

**The Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{ 
    private static List<ItemGroup> _datas = new List<ItemGroup>(); 

    public IActionResult Index() 
    { 
        return View(_datas); 
    } 

    [HttpPost] 
    public JsonResult PostJson([FromBody] ItemGroup data) 
    { 
        if (data != null) 
        { 
            _datas.Add(data); 
        } 

        return Json(new 
        { 
            state = 0, 
            msg = string.Empty 
        }); 
    } 
}
```